# Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

got a symfony project, updating from 5.1 to 6.4 LTS and doctrine to 3.0.0.

Got this Entity updating from annotations to PHP8 attributes:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    #[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: "App\Repository\SottocontiUtentiRepository")]
    class SottocontiUtenti
    {
        #[ORM\Id]
        #[Column(type: "integer")]
        private int $utente_id;

        #[ORM\Id]
        #[Column(type: "integer")]
        private int $pratica_id;

        #[ORM\Id]
        #[Column(type: "integer")]
        private int $finanziamento_id;

        #[Column(type: "string")]
        private $nome;

        #[Column(type: "string")]
        private $cognome;

        // Ripristino della relazione
        #[ORM\ORM\Id()]
        #[ManyToOne(targetEntity: Sottoconti::class, inversedBy: "utenti")]
        #[JoinColumn(name: "sottoconto_id", referencedColumnName: "sottoconto_id", nullable: true)]
        private ?Sottoconti $sottoconto_id;  // Nota l'utilizzo del tipo per Sottoconti

        #[Column(type: "float", nullable: true)]
        private $importo_deliberato;

        #[Column(type: "string", nullable: true)]
        private $rientro;


        public function getUtenteId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->utente_id;
        }

        public function setUtenteId(int $utente_id): self
        {
            $this->utente_id = $utente_id;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getSottocontoId(): ?Sottoconti
        {
            return $this->sottoconto_id;
        }

        public function setSottocontoId(?Sottoconti $sottoconto_id): self
        {
            $this->sottoconto_id = $sottoconto_id;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getPraticaId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->pratica_id;
        }

        public function setPraticaId(int $pratica_id): self
        {
            $this->pratica_id = $pratica_id;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getFinanziamentoId(): ?int
        {
            return $this->finanziamento_id;
        }

        public function setFinanziamentoId(int $finanziamento_id): self
        {
            $this->finanziamento_id = $finanziamento_id;

            return $this;
        }

        public function getImportoDeliberato(): ?float
        {
            return $this->importo_deliberato;
        }

        public function setImportoDeliberato(?float $importo_deliberato): self
        {
            $this->importo_deliberato = $importo_deliberato;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function getRientro()
        {
            return $this->rientro;
        }

        /**
         * @param mixed $rientro
         */
        public function setRientro($rientro): void
        {
            $this->rientro = $rientro;
        }
    }
```

Getting this error:
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "App\Entity\SottocontiUtenti". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

Tried to Google it and ask to Gemini ADV or ChatGPT.
Nothing works.
Also tried this way:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/3.0/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#composite-and-foreign-keys-as-primary-key

But still got the same error.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot,
Giacomo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the actual primary id field of the `importo_deliberato` table, plus you should only use `#[ORM\Id]` at the primary id field and not at other foreign ids... here is an sample taken from the symfony demo app:

```php
...
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $author = null;
...
```